# 4 bytes to a Float in a swift gives an unexpectedly small result

Tags: swift, binary

I'm trying to reconstruct a float from a binary stream in Swift [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359333/4-bytes-to-a-swift-float). As far as I can tell, the bytes are correct, but the resulting float is not.

```
func didReceive(data: NSData!) {
    var x:Float = 0

    var bytes:[UInt8] = [UInt8](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&bytes, range: NSMakeRange(0, 4))
    memcpy(&x, bytes, 4)

    NSLog("x:%f bytes:[%d, %d, %d, %d]", x, bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
}
```

This function prints out the following:

```
x:0.000000 bytes:[25, 0, 0, 0]
```

When I inspect `x` in the debugger, it reports the value as:

```
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000350324616
```

However, the bytes `[25,0,0,0]` should be hex `0x19000000`, which I think [should translate to about `6.617`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=19000000).

Where's my mistake here. Is a Swift float not a IEEE754 32 bit float?

Comment: This looks kind of like an endianness issue, but I have no experience with Swift and am unable to really diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a little-endian platform, so your array is equivalent to the 32-bit integer `0x00000019`, which, as an IEEE single precision floating-point number, is [approximately 3.5 * 10<sup>-44</sup>](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=00000019).

Comment: Interesting. So if I add a `bytes = bytes.reverse()` line in there, `x` becomes `0.0000000000000000000000066174449` which seems to have the right digits at least, but is still quite a few orders of magnitude off.

Comment: No, it's not any orders of magnitude off. The page you linked gives an answer of about 6.617 * 10^-24. That's what the "E-24" suffix means.

Comment: Haha! Missed that. Thanks rob

Answer (score 2):

Double-check the [page you linked to](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=19000000).  It shows 0x19000000 translates to 6.617…*E-24*.

Coming at it from the other direction, you can get the hex pattern of 6.617 like this:

```
String(unsafeBitCast(6.617 as Float, UInt32.self), radix: 16)
```

which gives you [0x40D3BE77](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=40D3BE77).

BTW if you want to try a way to do it without the `memcpy`, this should work:

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [0x40,0xD3,0xBE,0x77]

let f = bytes.reverse().withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    UnsafePointer<Float>($0.baseAddress).memory
}
```