# How to convert bytes to a float value in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, byte, nsmutabledata

This is my code to convert byte data to float. I tried every answers given in this site. I am getting exponential value for this  "<44fa0000>" byte data

```
    static func returnFloatValue(mutableData:NSMutableData)->Float
    {
       let qtyRange = mutableData.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 4))
       let qtyString = String(qtyRange)
       let qtyTrimString = qtyString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>"))
       let qtyValue =  Float(strtoul(qtyTrimString, nil, 16)/10)
       return qtyValue
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What value do you expect?

Comment: @MartinR a float value

Comment: `1.15723e+09` (what you call "exponential value") *is* a float value. If that is not what you expect then tell us what the result should be and why. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Value should be 2000.0

Comment: Btw, you asked a similar question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36812583/1187415, but never cared to respond on the answer. If an answer does not work for you then you can leave a comment and ask for clarification.

Comment: Sorry for not replying Martin R, But that question was different , that question was about conversion from float to byte, i think so there is some issue of big endian and little endian,

Comment: what do you mean by byte data. give one example input and output

Comment: This is my input "<44fa0000>" and output should be 2000.0

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to convert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`<44fa0000>` is the *big-endian* memory representation of the
binary floating point number `2000.0`. To get the number back from
the data, you have to read it into an `UInt32` first, convert from
big-endian to host byteorder, and then cast the result to 
a `Float`.

In **Swift 2** that would be

```
func floatValueFromData(data: NSData) -> Float {
    return unsafeBitCast(UInt32(bigEndian: UnsafePointer(data.bytes).memory), Float.self)
}
```

Example:

```
let bytes: [UInt8] =  [0x44, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00]
let data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: 4)

print(data) // <44fa0000>
let f = floatValueFromData(data)
print(f) // 2000.0
```

In **Swift 3** you would use `Data` instead of `NSData`, and the
`unsafeBitCast`  can be replaced by the `Float(bitPattern:)`
initializer:

```
func floatValue(data: Data) -> Float {
    return Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } ))
}
```

In **Swift 5** the `withUnsafeBytes()` method of `Data` calls the closure with an (untyped) `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`, and you can `load()` the value from the raw memory:

```
func floatValue(data: Data) -> Float {
    return Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot martin..:)

Comment: @MartinR Can you please add reverse of this process, means float to bytes , It's very urgent.

Comment: How this will work when we have 8 bytes and want to convert into 2 floats? Like in objective c I do have ``` union {
    float f[2];
    unsigned char bytes[8];
} u;                                                          
NSLog(@"mean: %f", u.f[0] ); NSLog(@"variance: %f", u.f[1] );   
```. 
How this one will look like in swift

Comment: @Kapil: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023838/1187415, where I posted more code about converting values and arrays of values to and from data.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some **swift 5**:

```swift
let data = Data([0x44, 0xfa, 0x00, 0x00]) // 0x44fa0000
let floatNb:Float = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float.self) }

// note that depending on the input endianess, you could add .reversed() to data
let floatNb:Float = data.reversed().withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float.self) }
```

**WARNING**: this sample throws if your Data is under 4 bytes..

.

Safe Data extension:

```swift
extension Data {
    enum Endianess {
        case little
        case big
    }

    func toFloat(endianess: Endianess = .little) -> Float? {
        guard self.count <= 4 else { return nil }

        switch endianess {
        case .big:
            let data = [UInt8](repeating: 0x00, count: 4-self.count) + self
            return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float.self) }
        case .little:
            let data = self + [UInt8](repeating: 0x00, count: 4-self.count)
            return data.reversed().withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float.self) }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tests:**

```swift
let opData        = Data([0x44, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00])
let nb42          = Data([0x42, 0x28])
let nb42bigEndian = Data([0x28, 0x42])
let tooBig        = Data([0x44, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])

print("opData:        \(opData.toFloat())")
print("nb42:          \(nb42.toFloat())")
print("nb42bigEndian: \(nb42bigEndian.toFloat(endianess: .big))")
print("tooBig:        \(tooBig.toFloat())")
```

*you may find a faster way but this was good enough for my needs*

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
static func returnFloatValue(data: NSMutableData) -> Float {
    let bytes = [UInt8](data as Data)
    var f: Float = 0

    memcpy(&f, bytes, 4)
    return f
}
```

And you can see it in action here:

```
var initialValue: Float = 19.200

let data = NSMutableData(bytes: &initialValue, length: 4)

func returnFloatValue(data: NSMutableData) -> Float {
    let bytes = [UInt8](data as Data)
    var f: Float = 0

    memcpy(&f, bytes, 4)
    return f
}

var result:Float = returnFloatValue(data: data)

print("f=\(result)")// f=19.2
```

Comment: i am getting this error Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int' (0x111dbd1a0) to 'Swift.UInt8' (0x111dbc858).

Comment: What swift version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

For 64 bit values the code is:

```
static func longBitsToDouble(x : Int64) -> Float64
{ return Float64(bitPattern: UInt64(x)) }
```

Swift 4+.