# Swift 3 how to parse DATA

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My Swift 3 code has a Foundation [Data](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data) collection of bytes (read from an SQlite BLOB). The internal content of the data has multiple blocks with this structure:

```
 {
     UINT32  count;  // number of points in this trkseg
     UINT32  colour; // RGB colour of the line drawn for this trkseq
     Double lat;  // latitude of 1st point
     Double long; // longitude of 1st point
     Coord  point[count-1] // array of points (2nd to last points)
}

typedef struct {
     Float lat   // difference in latitude of this point from the lat of the 1st point
     Float long  // difference in longitude of this point from the lat of the 1st point
 } Coord;
```

This is very easy to parse in C and Java. Unfortunately I cannot work out the best way to parse this with Swift 3. I'm not asking you how to parse this exact data layout, but just for recommendations and best practices for parsing such raw data with Swift 3. From web searches and Apple documentation I'm left very confused!

***ANSWER - Thanks to Martin R for getting me on the right track. I'm adding some code here to show how I solved this in case it will help others. As Martin said, there are many ways to solve this. My solution ensures the blob data, which is in network endian order (big endian) will always be parsed correctly regardless of the host endianness.

```
/// Parse the SQLite data blob to add GPS track segments
///
/// - Parameter data: GPS track information
private func addTracks(_ data: Data) {

    // The data holds compressed GPX data. It has multiple track segments.
    // It has a block of binary data per track segment with this structure:
    //     {
    //         UINT32  count;  // number of points in this trkseg
    //         UINT32  colour; // RGB colour of the line drawn for this trkseq
    //         Double lat;  // latitude of 1st point
    //         Double long; // longitude of 1st point
    //         Coord  point[count-1] // array of points (2nd to last points)
    //    }
    //
    //    typedef struct {
    //         Float lat   // difference in latitude of this point from the lat of the 1st point
    //         Float long  // difference in longitude of this point from the lat of the 1st point
    //     } Coord;

    var dataCount = data.count // number of data bytes

    var pointCount = 0     // counts coordinates per trkseg
    var colour:UInt = 0
    var lat:Double = 0.0
    var long:Double = 0.0
    var bigEndian = true
    var i = 0

    // From http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114730/type-to-byte-array-conversion-in-swift
    if (NSHostByteOrder() == NS_LittleEndian) {
        bigEndian = false
    }

    while (dataCount >= 40) {
        pointCount = Int(self.uint32Value(data: data.subdata(in: i..<i+4), isBigEndian: bigEndian))
        i = i+4

        if (pointCount < 2 || ((pointCount-1)*8 + 24 > dataCount)) {
            print("ERROR, pointCount=\(pointCount)")
            break
        }
        colour = UInt(self.uint32Value(data: data.subdata(in: i..<i+4), isBigEndian: bigEndian))
        i = i+4
        let firstLat = self.doubleValue(data: data.subdata(in: i..<i+8), isBigEndian: bigEndian)
        i = i+8
        let firstLong = self.doubleValue(data: data.subdata(in: i..<i+8), isBigEndian: bigEndian)
        i = i+8
        print("pointCount=\(pointCount) colour=\(colour) firstLat=\(firstLat) firstLong=\(firstLong)")

        for _ in 1..<pointCount {
            lat = firstLat - Double(self.floatValue(data: data.subdata(in: i..<i+4), isBigEndian: bigEndian))
            i = i+4
            long = firstLong - Double(self.floatValue(data: data.subdata(in: i..<i+4), isBigEndian: bigEndian))
            i = i+4
            print("lat=\(lat) long=\(long)")
        }
        dataCount = dataCount - 24 - (pointCount-1)*8;
    }
}

private func floatValue(data: Data, isBigEndian: Bool) -> Float {
    if (isBigEndian) {
        return Float(bitPattern: UInt32(littleEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } ))
    }
    else {
        return Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }))
    }
}

private func doubleValue(data: Data, isBigEndian: Bool) -> Double {

    if (isBigEndian) {
        return Double(bitPattern: UInt64(littleEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } ))
    }
    else {
        return Double(bitPattern: UInt64(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } ))
    }
}

private func uint32Value(data: Data, isBigEndian: Bool) -> UInt32 {

    if (isBigEndian) {
        return data.withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee }
    }
    else {
        let temp: UInt32 = data.withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee }
        return temp.bigEndian
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use the

```
public func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType, ContentType>(_ body: (UnsafePointer<ContentType>) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
```

method to access and dereference the bytes in the data.
The placeholder type `ContentType` can be inferred from the context:

```
let color: UInt32 = data.subdata(in: 0..<4).withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
// ...
let lat: Double = data.subdata(in: 8..<16).withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
// ...
```

As of Swift 4 you can use subscripting to extract the data:

```
let color: UInt32 = data[0..<4].withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
// ...
let lat: Double = data[8..<16].withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
// ...
```

If all fields are properly aligned for their type then you can
use the

```
public func load<T>(fromByteOffset offset: Int = default, as type: T.Type) -> T
```

from `UnsafeRawPointer`:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    let rawPointer = UnsafeRawPointer(bytes)
    let color = rawPointer.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: UInt32.self)
    // ...
    let lat = rawPointer.load(fromByteOffset: 8, as: Double.self)
    // ...
}
```

On a lower level you can use `memcpy` which again works with
arbitrarily aligned data:

```
var color: UInt32 = 0
var lat: Double = 0
data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    memcpy(&color, bytes, 4)
    // ...
    memcpy(&lat, bytes + 8, 8)
    // ...
}
```

I would probably use the first method, unless performance is an 
issue where you can use the second or third, depending on whether 
all fields are guaranteed to be aligned for their type or not.

Comment: Very helpful answer. The data is stored in network endian order (big endian) so needs to be converted to little endian.  I can convert the Uint32 values to little endian using "let color = rawPointer.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: UInt32.self).bigEndian". Such a conversion does not work for Double. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161034/how-to-convert-bytes-to-a-float-value-in-swift describes a way of handling the conversion. Is that the easiest? I cannot help thinking this is all too complex and there must be a simpler way.

Comment: @pbm: You can read it into a UInt64 first (with endian conversion) and then assign it to a Double with `Double(bitPattern: ...)`. – How would you do it in C or Java?